# Remaining only digits - Create method

Tags: django

I have a field which is called `fax`. It return a fax number under different form. For instance, it could be `1-800 222-2222`. I would like to create a property `compress_fax` get a product without anyone other information than digits. Hence, that property will change `1-800 222-2222` to `18002222222`. How could I do such thing?

```
from loanwolf.fields import PhoneField
fax = PhoneField(_('Fax'), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

and

```
class PhoneField(models.CharField):
    """
    450 123 4567
    450 123 4567 ext 123456
    """
    description = "A North American phone number with optional extension"
    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid': _('Please enter a valid phone number'),
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 30
        super(PhoneField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super(PhoneField, self).deconstruct()
        del kwargs["max_length"]
        return name, path, args, kwargs

    def validate(self, value, model_instance):
        # We only check that the first 10 digits are numbers
        super(PhoneField, self).validate(value, model_instance)
        _val = value.replace(' ', '').replace('-', '')[:10]
        if not re.match(r'\d{10}', _val):
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid'], code='invalid')
        return value

    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        value = super(PhoneField, self).pre_save(model_instance, add)
        return format_phone(value)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regular expressions to do this.

For example, say you have the following model:

```
import re

class Foo(models.Model):
    fax = models.CharField()
    ...

    @property
    def compress_fax(self):
        return re.sub('[^0-9]', '', self.fax)
```

This will remove any non-numerical value in the `fax` string.

Comment: I have modified my question. I don't know if it will change something.

Comment: @J.Doe What package are you using that utilizes `PhoneField()`, or did you create it?

Comment: I have modified my question.

Comment: @J.Doe Based on the code you provided, my solution should still work since it's extending the `CharField()` class. However, that code you provided also validates to remove any white spaces and dashes from the input. You shouldn't have `1-800 222-2222` as a value at all. It should automatically return `18002222222`. Granted, it only validates the first 10 characters, but it should still work.